# Include Collection of Collection in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I'm using Entity Framework 4.3

I have 3 tables, Lender, Product and ProductDetail

A Lender has multiple Products and a Product has Multiple ProductDetail rows

Here's a chunk of code I'm trying to use:

```
    Lender SingleOrDefault(Expression<Func<Lender, bool>> predicate)
    {
        using (var uow = new UnitOfWork(Connections.LoanComparision))
        {
            var r = new Repository<Lender>(uow.Context);

            return r.Find(predicate)
                .Where(x =>
                    x.IsPublished &&
                    x.Products.Any(y => y.IsPublished))
                .Include(x => x.Products.SelectMany(y => y.ProductDetails))
                .SingleOrDefault();
        }
    }
```

The issue is with the Include - I'm trying to get the Lender => Products => ProductDetails. I can't see the table in intellisense even though I know it is linked correctly. I thought the SelectMany might work but it gives me a runtime error.

Any ideas as to how this can be achieved?

Comment: `.Include(x => x.Products.Select(y => y.ProductDetails))` will work

Comment: Thanks for this guys - works a treat. If someone want's to create an answer I'll award the points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do `selectmany` however it is for  flatten `list of list`  to `list`.

To include relevant list you should do select as noted in comments noted by Developer user

```
Include(x => x.Products.Select(y => y.ProductDetails))
```